# How to Structure FetchXML to Obtain All Entities from Dynamics Online?

Tags: ssis, salesforce, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using a third party toolset to export data from a Dynamics Online portal.  I need to upload the data into Salesforce ultimately.

My current SSIS package has a CozyRoc Data Flow Task Plus inside a For Each Loop Container.  The Data Flow contains a CozyRoc Dynamics Source and and OLEDB Destination which is set to a local SQL Server.

All the FetchXML examples I've seen thus far refer to a specific entity.  Can the FetchXML be structured something like:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="*">
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

I'm also wondering if storing the data in SQL Server is the best destination?  Since I have tables and fields to create in Salesforce, I'm thinking this is a good holding tank.  However, would flat files be a better way to go here?

Comment: Knowing nothing of the specifics of what you're doing, I will say that I ran into a similar error where the underlying data had 0x1A in it which caused the XML to blow up (for Excel). Perhaps you're running into a similar situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FetchXML requires you to specify the table(s) you are querying against, so you can't do the wildcard method you proposed.
I don't know much about Salesforce, so I can't help with that part - although I assume it can support file imports or programmatic insertions from an external DB.